# Unequal sized buttons JavaFX

Tags: button, javafx

When i create 2 buttons in gridpane using the following code, it gives me 2 unequal sized buttons. How can i fix this issue ?

```
/**
 * Set the appearance of buttons in the grid
 */
private void setButtonAppearance(Button button)
{
    button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    //button.setFont(font);
    button.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    button.setMinSize(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE);
    // doesn't start with focus or stay focused
    button.setFocusTraversable(false);
}

/**
 * Create buttons to perform allocation and deallocation of events to venues
 */
private void addButtons()
{
    allocateButton = new Button("Allocate Event");
    deallocateButton = new Button("Deallocate Event");

    //Set appearance of buttons
    setButtonAppearance(allocateButton);
    setButtonAppearance(deallocateButton);

    gridPane.add(allocateButton, 5, 30, 10, 1);
    gridPane.add(deallocateButton, columns-15, 30, 10, 1);
}
```

OUTPUT:
[image]

Regards !

Comment: why don't use prefix width?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible solutions, either set a preferred width for the button

```
private void setButtonAppearance(Button button) {
    button.setPrefWidth(60);
}
```

or set the columns which the buttons occur in to both have the same constraints. Something like this. Note, by default there aren't any ColumnConstraint objects in the the getColumnConstraints() array.

```
gridPane.getColumnConstraints()
        .add(new ColumnConstraints(10, 100, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
gridPane.getColumnConstraints()
        .add(new ColumnConstraints(10, 100, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
```

Self contained example

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    Button allocateButton = new Button("Allocate Event");
    Button deallocateButton = new Button("Deallocate Event");

    setButtonAppearance(allocateButton);
    setButtonAppearance(deallocateButton);

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    gridPane.add(allocateButton, 0, 0, 1, 1);
    gridPane.add(deallocateButton, 2, 0, 1, 1);
    gridPane.getColumnConstraints()
            .add(new ColumnConstraints(10, 100, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
    gridPane.getColumnConstraints()
            .add(new ColumnConstraints(10, 100, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));
    gridPane.getColumnConstraints()
            .add(new ColumnConstraints(10, 100, Double.MAX_VALUE, Priority.ALWAYS, HPos.CENTER, true));

    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(gridPane));
    primaryStage.show();
}

private void setButtonAppearance(Button button) {
    button.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    // button.setFont(font);
    button.setMaxSize(Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE);
    button.setMinSize(Double.MIN_VALUE, Double.MIN_VALUE);
    // doesn't start with focus or stay focused
    button.setFocusTraversable(false);
}
```

Either way, I'd recommend against coding JavaFX layouts by hand, instead take advantage of Scene Builder and FXML...